# Case Stament, GroupBy and Count not grouping correctly

Tags: group-by, count, case

I have a SQL that uses a case statement to combine two fields and a groupby with a count.
My query works without errors but it is not grouping/counting the data that has two different names but are given the same name in the case statement.

```
SELECT   EMPLY, 
         Case when CCode = 'L1' then 'LongTerm' 
              when CCode = 'D1' then 'ShortTerm' 
              when RPolicy = 'C1' then 'Custom' 
              when RPolicy = 'H1' then 'Custom' end AS [FileType], 
         Count(AccountNumber) AS Total 
FROM     dbo.Accounts 
WHERE    Date like '%2017%' 
GROUP BY EMPLY, RPolicy, CCode
ORDER BY 1
```

What I need to know is how can I group by my new column "File Type"?

Output:

```
EMPLY   File Type   Total
EMPLY1  LongTerm    12
EMPLY1  Custom      1
EMPLY1  Custom      5
EMPLY1  ShortTerm   3
EMPLY2  LongTerm    16
EMPLY2  Custom      3
EMPLY2  Custom      6
EMPLY2  ShortTerm   8
EMPLY3  LongTerm    20
EMPLY3  Custom      2
EMPLY3  Custom      10
EMPLY3  ShortTerm   4
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I'm using AQT/SQL Server

Comment: Just group by the case statement. and emply.   Eliminate RPolicy, CCode from the group by.  Note: If you have a record with ccode L1 and RPolicy H1 then the filetype will be longTerm it can't be both. and the case exists once if finds the first match.

Comment: You're output is becuase you're grouping by RPolicy. and CCode.  your group by should just be `GROUP BY Emply, Case when CCode = 'L1' then 'LongTerm' 
              when CCode = 'D1' then 'ShortTerm' 
              when RPolicy = 'C1' then 'Custom' 
              when RPolicy = 'H1' then 'Custom' end` if you get the same results then you've not eliminated RPolicy and CCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

(you can't use alias in the group by as it executes before the select, however, you can use the full case statement!)

```
SELECT   EMPLY, 
         Case when CCode = 'L1' then 'LongTerm' 
              when CCode = 'D1' then 'ShortTerm' 
              when RPolicy in ('C1','H1') then 'Custom' end AS [FileType], 
         Count(AccountNumber) AS Total 
FROM     dbo.Accounts 
WHERE    Date like '%2017%' 
GROUP BY EMPLY, Case when CCode = 'L1' then 'LongTerm' 
              when CCode = 'D1' then 'ShortTerm' 
              when RPolicy In ('C1','H1') then 'Custom' end
ORDER BY EMPLY, FileType, Total
```

This subquery should also work but it's overhead.

```
SELECT   A.EMPLY
       , A.FileType
       , Count(1) AS Total 
FROM     (SELECT EMPLY
               , Date
               , Case when CCode = 'L1' then 'LongTerm' 
                      when CCode = 'D1' then 'ShortTerm' 
                      when RPolicy in ('C1','H1') then 'Custom' 
                 end AS FileType
         FROM dbo.Accounts) A
WHERE    A.Date like '%2017%' 
GROUP BY A.EMPLY, A.FileType
ORDER BY A.EMPLY, A.FileType
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this and I get the same results.

I’m trying to create a report that tells me how many files each employee is doing. The C1 and H1 need to be counted as a combined category, “Custom”.

Comment: Is 'Date' in dbo.accounts a character data type or a date data type?  and its' VERY unlikely this could produce the same results.  we're grouping by something entirely different!

Comment: it's an intitation date, it all in the same data table

Comment: Yes but like '%2017%' implies string format, if it's a date you should really use the year function `year(date) = 2017`  I just don't like seeing dates as character data.  Dates should be dates. Numbers that have math done on them numeric and everything else character.

Comment: Yup, I get the same thing. I think it's grouping the C1 separately from the H1 when I want those two grouped and totaled together as "Custom"

Comment: Ok, then I'll combine them in the case... but that shouldn't matter!

Comment: I just seen what you added up top "in ('C1','H1')". I see where your going with that. I think this might work. I'll do some re-formatting and see what happens. Thanks for your help

Comment: The only way that would/should make a difference is if 'Custom' was different in both lines.

Comment: Doing my Case Statement as 'in' fixed it and restarting AQT for whatever reason. Many thanks!!!